# How to read GeoCSV with OGR?

Tags: ogr, csv, import, analysis

I have a GeoCSV file which stores the geometry in a WKT formatted cell following [this](http://giswiki.hsr.ch/GeoCSV#GeoCSV_file_format_specification) recommendation:

```
"identifier","date","geom","value"
"Dgf01","15.04.2013","POINT (52.404869 13.147457)","285"
"Erp06","19.07.2012","POINT (52.455153 13.603216)","170"
"Gbs02","06.08.2013","POINT (52.476737 13.215827)","305"
[...]
```

But it does not recognize the geometry field, it always says `Geometry: None`.

```
 $ ogrinfo -ro -geomfield "geom" geo.csv -al
INFO: Open of `geo.csv'
      using driver `CSV' successful.

Layer name: geo
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 3
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
identifier: String (0.0)
date: String (0.0)
geom: String (0.0)
value: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(geo):1
  identifier (String) = Dgf01
  date (String) = 15.04.2013
  geom (String) = POINT (13.147457 52.404869)
  value (String) = 285

[...]
```

I tried different formats but it does not work at all. How to read GeoCSV with OGR correctly?

Comment: GeoCSV is not yet supported. It will be supported in GDAL/OGR >=2.1. See  last section of the CSV driver doc - http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html You can try to install a trunk/2.1dev snapshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an older version of GDAL/OGR, you can use [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html) to cast the `geom` field to a geometry. For example:

```sh
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "sample.shp" "geo.csv" -sql "SELECT *, CAST(geom as geometry) FROM geo"
```

This will create a new shapefile using the WKT data as the geometry. You can use the same query with `ogrinfo` as well:

```sh
ogrinfo -ro -sql "SELECT *, CAST(geom as geometry) FROM geo" "geo.csv"
```

Comment: Nice! Ps thought I recognised your avatar, thanks for the python training last week : )

Comment: Cheers @Luke - glad you enjoyed it!